# Turning a Data.Frame with 28441 Rows in it to a Dataframe with 28 Rows and 1000 Columns in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame with 28441 zip codes and this is the only column in the data frame. I want to turn it into 28 rows with 1000 zip codes each in it and one with  441 zip codes:

I have tried the following in the R Language:

```
zip.codes<-read.csv('E:/My Docments/zip_codes.csv', header= TRUE, fill=TRUE           
quote="\"", na.strings='NS', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(zip.codes)) {
 for(j in 1:1000) {
        new.zip.codes[j,i]<-zip.codes[i,j]
 }
}

I get the following error:
Error in new.zip.codes[j, i] <- zip,codes[i, j] : 
incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Each zip code is unique and is not repeated.

What am I missing?  Your help is appreciated.

Robert

Comment: So you want a data frame with 29 rows and 1000 columns? With the last 560-odd columns in row 29 being blank?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to do this once. If you have a number of lists of zip codes of different lengths you will need to modify this somewhat.

```
Zip<-seq(1:28441)        #fake zip codes for example
Zip[28842:29000]<-NA     #pads the zip codes to fit nicely in matrix
Zipmat<-matrix(data=Zip,nrow=29, ncol=100) #now in a 29 row by 100 column matrix
```

the help on the matrix() command has a couple of options (dimnames, byrow) that you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language this is coded in but I think I understand your problem.  If your original is all in the first column of zip.codes(I assume this is the old dataframe), you want [i,1] meaning row i, first column.  Your j should go from 1 to

```
for (i in 1:length(zip.codes)) {
  k = i % 1000
  for(j in 1:1000) {
    new.zip.codes[k,j]<-zip.codes[i,1]
  }
}
```

Using the % as a [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator, you can pick out the row number you want, had have j as your column control.  This is extremely useful when you know your fixed table size.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above results in the following error:      Error in new.zip.codes{k,j}<-zip.codes[i,1]: incorrect number of subscripts on matrix